# Securing Dynamic pages without Controllers in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to apply security (authentication & authorization) for " Dynamic pages without Controllers" in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just access the session, e.g:

```
@{
  var session = base.GetSession<MyAuthUserSession>();

  if (session.IsAuthenticated) {
    //Is Authenticated...
  }
  else {
    //Not Authenticated...
  }
}
```